# How to set face color according to vertex in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

im using three.js 106 ver. I'm generating terrain (starting with plane geometry) using  some algortihm, and i want to color terrain according to its veritces z value. Here is what i got so far

```
    const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(
  170,
  150,
  rows,
  cols
);

   ...

for (let y = 0; y < rows + 1; y++) {
  for (let x = 0; x < cols + 1; x++) {
    const pos = x * rows + y;
    const vertex = geometry.vertices[pos];
    if (vertex) {
       vertex.z = myAlgorithm();
    }
```

but since there are twice more as many faces as vertices it's not as simple as

```
geometry.faces[pos].color.set(myColorAlgorithm())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but since there are twice more as many faces as vertices

I'm afraid this statement is not true. There are more faces than vertices since duplicated vertices are getting merged. However, there is no 2:1 relationship.

Try to use `BufferGeometry` instead of `Geometry` since working with pure vertex data should make the code more clear. The code for this could look like so:

```
const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 1, 1, rows, cols );

const position = geometry.attributes.position;

const colors = [];
const color = new THREE.Color();

for ( let i = 0; i < position.count; i ++ ) {

    const z =  Math.random() * 0.2; // instead of myAlgorithm()

    position.setZ( i, z );

    const s = z * 5; // values  in the range [0,1]

    color.setHSL( 0.4, s, 0.5 );

    colors.push( color.r, color.g, color.b );

}

geometry.addAttribute( 'color', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute( colors, 3 ) );
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/zj8d1m2v/3/

`three.js R106`